# Access devise current_user variable in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've got Rails (4.0) running Devise gem (3.1.0) using model `User`. I have controller named `CollectionsController` and I want to get current logged in user object with Devise's accessor method `current_user` in this controller.

And after that it returns `undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for CollectionsController:Class`. The most interesting thing is that when I'm trying to do the same in another controller, for example `PagesController` — everything works perfectly!
**UPD:** sharing the "code" of my controller :)

```
class CollectionsController < ActionController::Base
    def index
         @user = current_user
    end
end
```

the source of `current_user` method is defined by Devise, not me. So I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Please share your code under CollectionsController and any code related to the current_user method

Comment: Is that code placed in an action or just in the middle of the controller like that?

Comment: yeah, sorry, it's placed inside `index` action

Comment: Is there a reason why you're inheriting from ActionController::Base rather than ApplicationController?

Comment: Guys, sorry, I've found the problem. The case is the folder I created in controllers folder for backup purposes and it seems that there was some kind of conflict or what. When I deleted it everything started to work. As for the inheriting from `ActionController::Base` no, there is no reason. I've just tried all available options in despair :) And it didn't work with both of them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`current_user` is a convenience method made available by Devise to `ApplicationController`. Your controller should be inheriting from it:

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController
```

It seems you may be conflating `ActiveRecord::Base` (subclassed by models) with `ActionController` (subclassed by controllers). According to [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html):

> By default, only the ApplicationController in a Rails application inherits from ActionController::Base. All other controllers in turn inherit from ApplicationController.

Comment: See [lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/4681f81ce6b643cd55d7404500ee02ab18bab5df/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb) @ github repo for more info

Answer (score 4):

Add `before_action :authenticate_user!`
 to your controller.

see:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Some controllers could access `current_user` and others could not.  In one case, it was an `erb` file that was accessing `current_user` but only after asking `user_signed_in?` I added that check in my controller code and voila!  `current_user` was available.

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` is an *instance* method, not a *Class* method.

Notice `CollectionsController:Class` mentions `Class` which means you are calling  `current_user` inside the class instead of an instance.

```rb
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController

  current_user # wrong place. Here, current_user is on the Class.

  def index
    current_user # right place. Here, current_user is on the instance.
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController
    include Devise::Controllers::Helpers 
    def index
         @user = current_user
    end
end
```

Add (include Devise::Controllers::Helpers) in your controller as shown above.