# rails 3.2, mongo, and devise not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise

I had a fully functional Rails 3.2 app with MySQL, I am trying to convert to MongoDB. I thought it would be a simple conversion but in my `application.html.erb` template, I reference `current_user` and I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<#<Class:0x007f98674f58d8>:0x007f9867358840>
```

Any idea why this is failing?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Can you post the current_user code in your application.html.erb and ApplicationController? Switching to MongoDB shouldn't have affected this. See also this QA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147729/access-current-user-variable-in-controller-rails-devise

Answer (score 0):

It's not straight forward, You need to address below technical stuffs.

1. Make sure to integrate Mongoid ORM for mongodb
2. Dump the existing database straight to MongoDB
3. Migrate the data(not need schema)
4. Refactor models as needed(attributes on model)

I hope it's will help.